# Ending a PHP File

Tags: php

I am getting the following error:
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /usr/www/whatsup4/Tool/run.php on line 31**

Here is my code:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'whatsup4_tool');
define('DB_USER', 'whatsup4');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxxx');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     }

     $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

     if (!$db_selected) {
     die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
     }

     $value1 = $_POST['64id'];
     $value2 = $_POST['b64id'];
     $value3 = $_POST['info'];
     $value4 = $_POST['ev'];

     $sql = "INSERT INTO whatsup4_tool (64id, b64id, info, ev) VALUES ('$value', '$value2', 
     '$value3', '$value4');
     mysql_query($sql);

     mysql_close();
?>
```

Is there anything else I need to add at the end? I have never coded using SQL before. If it is relevant, here is the HTML code:

```
<form action="run.php" method="post"/>
<p>User's 64 ID: <input type="text" name="64id"/></br>
<p>Your 64 ID: <input type="text" name="b64id"/></br>
<p>Infringement: <input type="text" name="info"/></br>
<p>Evidence: <input type="text" name="ev"/></br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: The syntax coloring applied to your code in the question body should give a pretty strong hint as to what's wrong...

Comment: Try to use a proper editor to help you. Like `PHPStorm`, `Netbeans`, `ZendStudio` or other

Comment: I used Adobe Edge Code to make it, but I just opened it with notepad while I copied it over. I can see my mistake now and how I can avoid it in the future, so thanks.

Comment: you might want to take a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1 cuz sql injection isnt cool....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving the error since you have missed a double quote:

This code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO whatsup4_tool (64id, b64id, info, ev) VALUES ('$value', '$value2', 
 '$value3', '$value4')<double-quote-missing>;
```

Should be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO whatsup4_tool (64id, b64id, info, ev) VALUES ('$value', '$value2', 
 '$value3', '$value4')";
```

Answer (score 2):

you missed `"` (closing double quote) on query close

try replace

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO whatsup4_tool (64id, b64id, info, ev) VALUES ('$value', '$value2', 
     '$value3', '$value4');
```

to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO whatsup4_tool (64id, b64id, info, ev) VALUES ('$value', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4')";
```